# What's the difference between FileManager.SearchPathDomainMasks such as userDomainMask and localDomainMask on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, filesystems, file-management

Most document-based iOS apps access the filesystem like so:

`FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first`

My question is regarding the second argument `userDomainMask`. Does that have any purpose on iOS? If so what's the difference between all of the options?

Unfortunately Apple's [one-liner docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/searchpathdomainmask/1417507-localdomainmask) for some [FileManager.SearchPathDomainMasks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/searchpathdomainmask) doesn't help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, NSSearchPathDomainMask) {
    NSUserDomainMask = 1,       // user's home directory --- place to install user's personal items (~)
    NSLocalDomainMask = 2,      // local to the current machine --- place to install items available to everyone on this machine (/Library)
    NSNetworkDomainMask = 4,    // publically available location in the local area network --- place to install items available on the network (/Network)
    NSSystemDomainMask = 8,     // provided by Apple, unmodifiable (/System)
    NSAllDomainsMask = 0x0ffff  // all domains: all of the above and future items
};
```

Comment: This would make sense on Mac OS, but on iOS can we get to Network, System, or Library? I didn't think those exist the same as on Mac OS.