# What does SearchPathDomainMask mean in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

In swift, we use `Filemanager.default.url(for:in:)` to get user directories or system directories. And we pass arguments typed `SearchPathDirectory` and `SearchPathDomainMask` to specify what urls we need.

My question is the symbol of second parameter's type contains the word "mask" but I have no idea of what it actually hide. The actual work seems like "a group of directories' or 'what domain directories belong to".

I have no problem with actual programming with it but it just makes me curious.

Comment: Please have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/searchpathdomainmask).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66912659/whats-the-difference-between-filemanager-searchpathdomainmasks-such-as-userdoma

Comment: `NSSearchPathDomainMask` is a bit mask In Objective-C.